# Append prefix to caddy route

Tags: caddy

I want to achieve the opposite behavior of “uri strip_prefix”: I always want to add a /foo in front of the url.

e.g.

[domain] → [domain]/foo

[domain]/a → [domain]/foo/a

I'm using Caddy version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: it's just `rewrite * /foo{uri}`